# Font sizing of embedded pdf in html

Tags: html, pdf

I have a brief technical document/note with scientific symbols in pdf.  Actually, it's only a half page.  To show it on my website I have it saved as a png and then I display the png.  But then it does not scale well with different display sizes.

My Adobe pdf viewer scales perfectly with different displays even though the technical document was typeset at 12pt font size.

What's the scaling solution for html on my website?  I cannot recreate the technical symbols in html so that they look so good.  Is displaying/embedding a pdf a good solution?  But what if I only want half of the pdf page to be displayed since only half has any print?

Comment: Have you considered rendering LaTeX on your website using something like MathJax? LaTeX is pretty good at rendering most symbols.

Comment: Yes, ideally LaTeX, which was how the pdf was originally produced.  But I use specific TeX packages for my field to get the symbols.  And LaTeX is easy to space.